# Implementing FSM on multiple class UNITY3D

Tags: c#, unity, design-patterns

I am recently implementing design patterns on my project, while researching around I came across many advance techniques like HFSM ,Behaviour trees.

I did implemented behavior trees wherever required in project, though I am quite confused over how to implement FSM on multiple classes of same game object.

For example, suppose my object is running and he has following classes,

```
Score.cs,

Inputs.cs,

MovementController.cs

PlayerController.cs

xyz.cs,

Abc.cs
```

Coming to my main point,how can I implement state machine which will dynamically change code in the above multiple scripts as state changes.

The only work around I can think of is using one main game manager script which will pass event to this scripts as state changes and all the classes will catch events and will run accordingly. But problem with this approach is this,code will fall if multiple coroutines are running on given scrips and how all scripts will get on same paper at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it a little bit difficult to follow the entire thread of your question.

However at the most basic level, in a simple FSM you could either just query the current state of your StateMachine (i.e. assuming its a singleton manager class etc : StateMachine.Instance.GetState ) and then do the necessary long-winded if or switch statement logic depending on which state is returned.

Alternatively, for something a bit more loosely coupled and dynamic you could just have each relevant Class subscribe to a OnStateChanged event equivalent and react to specific states with callbacks.

There isn't a right way to implement a FSM, however you can take a steer from one of the many online resources eg:

http://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/2f6esc/c_need_help_understanding_a_finite_state_machine/

http://www.voidinspace.com/2013/05/a-simple-finite-state-machine-with-c-delegates-in-unity/

------ EDIT UPDATE ------

The idea is that if you're going to roll your own GameStateManager in the Unity engine, then each state would essentially have it's own methods such as Update etc. These methods would execute sequentially as per the norm.

You could manage your state transitions with a State stack container. This way multiple states could be queued up and pushed into the stack, and then executed in order i.e. GameState-->MenuState-->ControlsMenuSubState etc. At the end of each frame you could then do some bookkeeping and check if it's OK to roll onto the next state i.e. pop the current state and then execute the next state object on the GameState stack.

It does sound like you're overcomplicating things by coupling each class to each State of the game. The classes generally shouldn't know or care which state they're in as it's the State's job to call into other classes, not the other way around.

Unity's normal Scene methodology is also suitable. You could just use Scenes to transition between major games states, and then use the Unity GUI for Overlay states such as Inventory or Menu states which need to run in the current state. All you would need is at least 1 object to maintain your meta game state between scene transitions.

Comment: Thanks for the attachments, Actually my main concern is, suppose I have "GameState" class which changes gameState and then notifies to other classes that state has changed.Like if it throws "init" state,
Then how that GameState class will know that all the classes has done with their execution and waiting to go in next State ?

Comment: Ok, added an edit as requested.

Comment: Thanks for the breif ans, I get it I was over complicating things, Now I have integrated Events + GameState pattern with local states in each class.